# any met python import paramiko and Crypto err like "Not using mpz_powm_sec."?

Tags: python, linux, redhat

OS: redhat 5.2 i386

python: 2.7

err like:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Feb  7 2012, 11:16:30) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
/home/master/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py:57: PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.
  _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)
```

it's my libgmp version:

```
 ldconfig -p |grep libgmp
        libgmpxx.so.3 (libc6, hwcap: 0x0000000004000000) => /usr/lib/sse2/libgmpxx.so.3
        libgmpxx.so.3 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so.3
        libgmpxx.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so
        libgmp.so.3 (libc6, hwcap: 0x0000000004000000) => /usr/lib/sse2/libgmp.so.3
        libgmp.so.3 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3
        libgmp.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgmp.so
```

all above seems like related to libgmp,that confused me.PLZ show me some suggestion,thx!

Answer (score 6):

This is normal - RHEL 5 seems to have GMP version 4.x, and therefore the Python libraries are built against that version.

Rebuild the GMP library from [official source](http://gmplib.org/)s and rebuild your Python after that, if you really want to get rid of the warning.

You could consider upgrading to an more modern OS - EL5 will be EOP by the end of this year. Or at least update your OS to the latest revision (5.7)

Comment: though there is the warning,the script seems running ok.THX all the same!

Comment: In RHEL 6 for ppc64 I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and rebuilding python (in my case 2.7) was not sufficient. I had to reinstall *pycrypto* with pip after compiling the newer version of gmp, in fact, I don't know if rebuilding python was necessary but I still did it following Kimvais answer.